# Apply style to one child element of a custom panel?

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout, win-universal-app, panel

I've made my own implementation of a custom panel(which is mostly handling a Grid layout of items, depending on their size and the panel size).

I've to be able to "navigate" between items(with keyboard arrows) and give a visual style to one of them.

Currently I'm able to get the `UIElement` that should be highlighted, but I don't know:

- How I can apply a style?
- Which style to apply? Since I don't know what kind of element is contained, I was thinking to maybe apply some border around the cursor

Any idea how to proceed?

I will also have to "focus" this element, if this could help

Comment: you can use that custom panel as ItemsPanel for ListBox. ListBox allows to select 1 or more elements (creating an ItemContainer (ListBoxItem) for each data item), so you can customize selected ListBoxItem style as well

Comment: @ASh This seems to be an excellent idea! Where do you handle the keyboard keys? You should put an answer with your proposition

Answer (score 0):

The UIElement type doesn't have a concept of style, Style is a property defined on FrameworkElement, which derives from UIElement and provides a set of properties, events, and methods for WPF elements.

If you could cast your UIElement as a FrameworkElement you could apply the style like this

```
FrameworkElement frameworkElement = uiElement as FrameworkElement;

if (frameworkElement != null)
{
    frameworkElement.Style = myStyle;
}
```

Comment: Ok, that I could do, but what style to apply? Since I only know this is a FrameworkElement? I don't know much property around it

Comment: If you want to manually apply a style to it you would have to know what you are styling, otherwise the whole idea makes no sense. You could get the type of the element and use that to find a style that targets that type..

Answer (score 0):

you can use custom panel as ItemsPanel for ListBox, e.g.

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

the idea found here [ItemsControl: A-Z chapter I](http://drwpf.com/blog/2008/03/25/itemscontrol-i-is-for-item-container/)

ListBox wraps items into ListBoxItem container and supports (out of box) selection (1 or more items) and selected item highlight (can be customized with a new style). All arrows key are also working.

Comment: I will try, but I'm not sure how arrows keys can work with a grid layout(meaning that up-down should change the row, left-right should change the column)